# How to take only the first 30 rows in plotly express python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have an excel file with a column named 'Product' and 'Quantity'. In the Product column, there are over 100 different items (clothes, shoes, caps, hats ,etc) while the Quantity column shows how many of those products were sold.

```
**Product**     **Quantity**
Shirt A             2
Shirt A             5
Shirt C             1
Shirt A             9
Shoes B             3
```

I want to group all different items and count their total quantity but only for the 25 most sold products. in pandas it would be like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('directory\Sales.csv')

df_products = df[['Product', 
'Quantity']].groupby('Product').sum().head(25).sort_values(by='Quantity', ascending=False)
```

but how can I do this exact same thing in a histogram graph made in plotly.express? I tried this:

```
fig_product = px.histogram(data_frame=df_products, x='Product', y='Quantity')
```

This shows me all +100 products name and their quantities sold, but I only want the top 25 of those to show up for me. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in dataframe preparation

- `groupby().sum()` to get the totals required
- `sort_values().head()` for number of items you want to plot.  I've picked top 10 in this example
- there is no difference between histogram and Bar

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"product":np.random.choice(list("abcdefghijklmnonpqrstuvwxyz"), 200), "quantity":np.random.uniform(3,5,200)})

df = df.groupby("product", as_index=False).sum().sort_values("quantity", ascending=False).head(10)

go.Figure(go.Bar(x=df["product"], y=df["quantity"]))
px.histogram(data_frame=df, x='product', y='quantity')
```

[image]